# MDrivenServer on-premises - access via http, not https

Tags: mdriven

is access via HTTP to MDrivenServer disabled in new releases of MDrivenServer? Even if I setup correct WebServices_*.config files  MDrivenServer always returns System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   AppCompleteGenericCommon.Common.GetMDrivenServerUrl() in c:\capableobjectsbuild2017\source\AppCompleteGeneric\AppCompleteGeneric.Model\Common.cs:48
   AppCompleteGenericCommon.Common.ServerUsesSSL() in c:\capableobjectsbuild2017\source\AppCompleteGeneric\AppCompleteGeneric.Model\Common.cs:123
   AppCompleteGeneric.Global.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\capableobjectsbuild2017\source\AppCompleteGeneric\AppCompleteGeneric.PServerIis\Global.asax.cs:94
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +141
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware that we made such a change.
If you use http for development - consider a self signed cert and use this thing i chrome to skip the hassle of getting everything right :
https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Certificate

Comment: yes, self-signed cert is the solution for the 'classic' infra where MDriven is the webapp on the VM. In the 'container' infra it is a challenge - difficulties to upload model using Designer - The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state. Access to the container is via host's ip, but https://hostip:port/admin/serviceadmin.svc shows 'svcutil.exe http://containername:port/admin/ServiceAdmin.svc?wsdl

Comment: My problem related to the wcf config. Solved by settings in web.config section serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"